# is it possible to make nodejs/express script listen to same port(80) just like php

Tags: node.js

is it possible to make nodejs script listen to same port(80) just like php.

For php, it should be 
www.abc.com/script1.php

www.abc.com/script2.php

equal to

www.abc.com:80/script1.php

www.abc.com:80/script2.php

but for nodejs script(script1.js, script2.js), how to set parameters to make multi scripts listening to 80 and processing related script when get the requests?

Your comment welcome

Comment: that is not my question, I mean if it is possible for different nodejs script listen to same port?

Comment: There is nothing like "node scripts", you use routes in Express, which is a single process; do you mean using the same port of Apache? In that case you can't and you'd need a proxy.

Comment: Reading @CD's comment I got it - you just need module `http-proxy` [after having started your processes on different local ports, and having routed the traffic in 2 different routes, e.g. `/foo` -> `localhost:3333` and `/bar` -> `localhost:4444`].

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in a node.js solution check out [bouncy](http://substack.net/posts/5bd18d), a websocket and https-capable http router proxy/load balancer in node.js.

Define your routes.json like

```
 {
      "beep.example.com" : 8000,
      "boop.example.com" : 8001
 }
```

and then run bouncy using

```
 bouncy routes.json 80
```

other alternative to bouncy is [http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy)